# how to MYSQL compare values from same columns

Tags: mysql, sql

how do i compare 1 table in mysql?
with the following table

name table belajar

```
   id model name
   1 AAA AAA
   2 BBB BBB
   3 CCC CCC
```

and I want to generate a query

```
  id name model idmodel namemodel modelmodel
  1 AAA AAA 2 BBB BBB
  1 AAA AAA 3 CCC CCC
  2 BBB BBB 1 AAA AAA
  2 BBB BBB 3 CCC CCC
  3 CCC CCC 1 AAA AAA
  3 CCC CCC 2 BBB BBB
```

Comment: give more details ! what are your tables ? column names ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What **exactly** is "compared" in the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like maybe a self join is what you want here:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.name,
    t1.model,
    t2.id AS idmodel,
    t2.name AS namemodel,
    t2.model AS modelmodel
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.name <> t2.name AND
       t1.model <> t2.model;
ORDER BY
    t1.id,
    t2.id;
```

The join criteria is basically a cross join, except that you don't want to match two records if the names and models be the same.

Comment: @ArySyahputra . . . You can just use `t1.id <> t2.id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, that happens to work with the exact data given, but in general maybe the OP really did intend to use other field(s).